# About NFC data format

Tags: android, nfc

I'm newbie for NFC develop on Android.And I have some problems that confuse me.

1. Are NFCA,NFCB,NFCV,NDEF,NDEFFORMATABLE only data format of the NFC card data? How to find the detail format protocol of the data?

2.If NFCA,NFCB,NFCV,NDEF,NDEFFORMATABLE are only different in data format, why NFC card only support some of them rather than all of them?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The [BasicTagTechnology](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/TagTechnology.html) types are mainly communication protocols. The NDEF-related ones are data format or rather a standardized way of storing NDEF-data on the tags using the communication protocols and thus the tag functionality. For example, storing NDEF data in Mifare Classic tags also define standard authorization key.

You might start using only the NDEF format, than rather go with more advanced stuff later. Android has built-in support for various NDEF-related functionality. There is quite a few standardized NDEF Records. I've written a 'wrapper' [library](https://github.com/skjolber/ndef-tools-for-android) for [most of them](https://github.com/skjolber/ndef-tools-for-android/tree/master/ndeftools/src/org/ndeftools). You might want to start with TextRecord and the Android Application Record.